# Detect 'false' with laravel @forelse and stop looping

Tags: php, laravel

I have a loop which sometimes has no data. I'm trying to prevent the looping of data if the array item is empty/false etc.

```
@forelse($section['menu_items'] as $menu_item)

    MENU ITEMS

@empty

  {{-- No menu items available --}}

@endforelse
```

The value of `$section['menu_items']` is:
`/tmp/sage-cache/2acaf3eba50e1836f9f0ccc295cb9d19c73d0fec.php:105:boolean false`

Based on this error, it's still trying to loop but also falls back to the @else result too:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just check it before you try to loop through it?

```
@if(!empty($section['menu_items']))
    @foreach($section['menu_items'] as $menu_item)
        MENU ITEMS
    @endforeach
@else
    {{ -- No menu items available --}}
@endif
```

Comment: I did end up doing this, I just presumed `@forelse` was supposed to do this type of check too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@forelse($status->replies as $reply)

        <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>

    @empty

       <p>No replies</p>

 @endforelse
```